# How do I remove a single digit, numbered suffix, in parenthesis (e.g. file (2).ext --> file.ext) in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need to remove numeric extensions from files and while doing so not overwrite an existing file.

How would I go about this in Powershell?

Comment: Please don't use the question body to answer your question. Ask a question as if it is a standalone problem and then use the answer to provide your solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's a whole lot of code gymnastics, just to do this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads").FullName -match '\([0-9]{1,4}\)' | 
ForEach-Object {Rename-Item -Path $PSItem -NewName $($PSItem -replace '\([0-9]{1,4}\)') -WhatIf }
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\...\How do I remove a single digit... (e.g. file (2).ext --- file.ext)...  
Destination: C:\...\How do I remove a single digit, numbered suffix, in parenthesis (e.g. file .ext --- file.ext)...".
#>
```

Remove the -WhatIf to make things happen

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads").FullName -match '\([0-9]{1,4}\)' | 
ForEach-Object {Rename-Item -Path $PSItem -NewName $($PSItem -replace '\([0-9]{1,4}\)')}
# Results
<#
C:\...\How do I remove a single digit, numbered suffix, in parenthesis (e.g. file .ext --- file.ext) in Powershell- - Super User.url
#>
```

Of course, just use the ***Trim()*** method to deal with unneeded spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Same script as in question:

```
get-childitem * -file -recurse | where-object {
    $_.Name -match "^.*\([0-9]\)\.[^\.]*$"} | ForEach-Object {
        $path=($_.Directory.tostring())
        $ext=$_.Extension
        $baseLen=($_.BaseName.Length)
        $newLen=($baseLen-3)
        $newBase=($_.basename.ToString().substring(0,$newLen))
        if ($newBase.tostring().substring($newLen-1,1) -eq " ") {$newBase=($newBase.TrimEnd())}
        $newFile=($path+"\"+$newBase+$ext)
        if(!([system.io.file]::exists($newFile))) {Move-Item "$_" "$newFile"}
    }
```